# How to call a controller method from JavaScript when project is run under the IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to call the JavaScript function for counting the selected checkbox and in this function I have to call one statement for call the actionresult method of controller and perform to some function as active user and deactive user and return view() at end

Here is my code:

```
if (state == "Dec") {
    alert("Hello..Dear..you are DeActive");
    $.post('@Url.Action("UserDeactive","Admin", new{})' + '?Id=' + strvalue);
}
```

This statement works well in the normal project when I run project by press the F5, also using VS localhost.

But when I host my project in IIS, for accessing in LAN, this is not work  hold java script call but this statement are not call and not navigate to action result method ..for do some function..!
so please me ...All My Dear..! if you have any idea .!

this is my Controller Method:-

```
  public ActionResult UserActive(string Id)
    {

        int[] numbers = Id.Split(',').Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray();


        if (numbers != null)
        {
            foreach (int id in numbers)
            {
                User_Master u_master = db.User_Masters.Find(id);
                if (u_master.Is_active == "false")
                {
                    u_master.Is_active = "true";
                    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second argument of the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method which allows you to POST additional parameters to the server:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UserDeactive", "Admin")';
$.post(url, { id: strvalue }, function(result) {
    // handle the result of the AJAX call
});
```

Comment: sir...this statement also i have used but it does not work...!

Comment: This should work. If it doesn't then you have some other problem. Inspect the request with FireBug and you will be able to see the reason why is it failing. Also you haven't specified in your question, but in order to use the `@Url.Action` helper, you need to put this script inside your view, not in a separate javascript file. Is this the case? Also is the controller action being invoked?

Comment: sir..as per my review problem is there when call java script and when call this statement at URL appended some encoded ID..so what's reason...because my STRVALUE is string and pass in to Actionresult.. by the Id,,

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Try to inspect the AJAX request being sent to the server with FireBug and see what exactly does the server responds with.